# rgbdslam camera location

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to calculate or extract the camera location and pose within RGBDSlam. I've been poking at the RGBDSlam code for a while trying to figure out if data was able to be published or calculated somewhere but can't find anything. I think it is inferred somehow as the newest version prints the changed coordinate axis on each update. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11755/rgbdslam-camera-location/) by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the new snapshot (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam/evaluation) you can store the trajectory to file. Also, if you send the model, a transformation from /map to /openni_camera is published.
In the svn version, a transformation from /openni_camera to /slam_transform is published, where (somewhat confusing) /openni_camera acts as the fixed/map frame and /slam_transform is the moving camera postion.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on 2011-11-04**:
I was able to figure out how to use TF. I'm working on how to parse the output of TF to be able to set up a "coordinate system" so I can locate myself in a previously compiled map for comparison. Thanks!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-11-03**:
Which Version are you using? Do you know how to use TF?

**Comment by [drew212](https://answers.ros.org/users/1087/drew212/) on 2011-11-03**:
I looked through all the topics and nodes after sending the whole model and couldn't find anything labeled as openni_camera or slam_transform. Where should I be looking for the transforms? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure, but in GraphManager.cpp there is a method publishCorrectedTransforms(). Maybe it has what you are looking for. Otherwise you should check the addNode() method of GraphManager. I think that is where all the magic happens.

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1